# IAM Policy to allow user to run tests in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway, aws-iam-policy

I'm trying to make an IAM policy through which I can allow the user to run the tests in API Gateway without making changes to the resources. What policy should I grant the user?

Answer (score 0):

Use below policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need more details, please check this Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html

Comment: Thankyou sm. I'll try to use this and would let you know.

Comment: Welcome, you can contact us on https://www.cloudkaramchari.com/contact/